# Google sheets ARRAYFORMULA set length based upon another length dynamically sized

Tags: google-sheets

I need a second column to be the same height as the first one. However, I need to keep the empty spaces where they are. Do I need to focus on query to work this?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iBkX1B53vYQVUJ6j8dNOE_ck1dONidsqyNuO0lgSKHw/edit?usp=sharing The ArrayFormula example tab.

Comment: Would you be able to share an image/screenshot of your desired output when you say _"I need a second column to be the same height as the first one"_ for better understanding? Upon checking the sheet you've shared, you already have [this](https://imgur.com/a/p1LTbEl) & I'm unsure what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've modified the sheet to show the problem. I placed 'a' at what is suppose to be the bottom. The first column is fine. The second and third are suppose to be the same. The problem is the second and third don't have a limit like the first column.

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right, as seen on this [sample image](https://imgur.com/a/whi8e5s) when manually placing 'a', on column `B` for example,  it should have the same bottom as on the Column `A` and should not break the formula. Correct?

Comment: That's right, with arrayformula if somethings occupying a cell within the range it's suppose to modifying. That's what happens. Column A is fine because the filter is automatically limiting how many cells it's targeting even though I didn't set a limit. The other columns don't have that.

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
=FILTER(Projects!A:B; A:A<>"")
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem with this is some empty spaces are valid. Doing that moves the non-empty ones up.

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION

It seems `arrayformula` is fixed when it comes to filtering non-empty cells in a range you have set it up with. Since you have valid empty cells that you'd like to be disregarded, you should need to focus on using `query` instead, as you can specifically use a set of conditions towards the data you want to get.

### Example

> `=QUERY(Projects!2:1000,"SELECT B WHERE A is not null label B 'Projects'")`

- *NOTE: Place on Col `B`*

***OR***

> `=QUERY(Projects!2:1000,"SELECT A,B WHERE A is not null label A 'Projects', B 'Projects'")`

- *NOTE: Place on Col `A`*

### Test

- Test Sheet

> [image]